# Why is a PUT request not sent by my function when I call another function to refresh the window?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a Javascript function to send a PUT request to my Flask backend specifying a project with a certain id to be deleted, this function works as expected in sending a PUT request when it is set to run onclick for an HTML element. However, when I try adding another function to the onclick to refresh the window (to refresh the list of projects to reflect the deletion), the function will not send a PUT request.

What I don't understand is, why if my function works normally, does it then not work when I run another function after it? The function is called as can be seen by the confirm prompt, but doesn't send a PUT request (it does call the refresh function afterwards though).

[image: confirm function]
[image]

I tried using a single function onclick which then calls both functions, and both functions in onclick (functionA(); functionB();) but neither of these approaches works, unless I solely call one function the PUT request will not be sent.

My Javascript functions are:

```
function refreshWindow() {
    window.location.reload();
}

function deleteProject(pid) { // Function to send a put request to delete the project with ProjectID pid
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this project?")) {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var data = {};
        data.id = pid;
        data.action = "delete";
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        
        xhttp.open("PUT", currenturl, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xhttp.send(json);
    }
}

function deleteProjectRefresh(pid) {
    deleteProject(pid);
    refreshWindow();
}
```

and the relevant HTML element is: (the {{ project[0][0] }} part just inserts the ID into the HTML - Jinja template)

`<img onclick="deleteProjectRefresh({{ project[0][0] }})" title="Delete" src="../static/img/Delete Button.png"></td>`

Comment: The Ajax call is asynchronous and you’re not waiting for it to finish before refreshing the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `deleteProjectRefresh` then javascript will execute `deleteProject` and `refreshWindow` simultaneously. So your browser will refresh before it has the chance to run the Ajax request.

You can fix this by using a callback before calling `refreshWindow`

```
function refreshWindow() {
    window.location.reload();
}

function deleteProject(pid) { // Function to send a put request to delete the project with ProjectID pid
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this project?")) {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var data = {};
        data.id = pid;
        data.action = "delete";
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        
        xhttp.open("PUT", currenturl, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');

        // Add a call back for the onreadystatechange event
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
                refreshWindow(); //MOVED TO HERE
            }
        }
        xhttp.send(json);
    }
}

function deleteProjectRefresh(pid) {
    deleteProject(pid);
    //refreshWindow(); MOVE THIS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `refreshWindow()` function is called immediately after you fire the HTTP PUT, so it executes before the PUT returns anything, I am not sure if that is relevant.
Personally, I don't use `onClick()` at all, I always use an event to bind the code to an action, thereby separating the code and presentation.